# How to play videos in uiwebview ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, iframe, uiwebview

I'm building an article reading app for iphone.I'm parsing JSON content of article in uiwebview.
Some of the articles contains videos,But it does not display in the uiwebview.
JSON format for video is

```
    <iframe src=\"\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/hdstrm\" height=\"360\" width=\"640\" allowfullscreen=\"\" frameborder=\"0\">
```

The uiwebview display empty space at the place of video frame 
here is screen shot of uiwebview:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Displaying YouTube videos on iOS requires special treatment and is much less straight forward than you would expect (or hope). You can either display the entire YouTube page and let the user take it from there (or try to programmatically simulate a press on the play button), or you can "steal" the MP4 and play it using the media player.

The second option is better because it allows you to control the UI around the video and doesn't force you to display the entire YouTube page. However, it's important to stress that it requires quite a bit of work and is frowned upon by YouTube. In fact, they change the HTML structure of their pages every 2-3 months so that these mechanisms will break, and you won't be able to access the MP4 file directly without changing your code.

For more information on how to access the media file directly and play it, check out https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView

Comment: thanks @chonch,i did not get your point,in my case i just parsing the json content in uiwebview but videos are not displaying,i think i don't have to open the website of youtube.could you help me.

Comment: thanks @chonch,i want to do the same as in Techcrunch iOS app videos are in the articles just click on them and play,no need to load youtube page.